# SparkContext usage in high-volume application

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I'm trying to understand the "Cost of Spark Context", are they very heavy and would creating 500 Spark-Context in a single JVM a bad-design.

In the context of a Insurance company, Customer-Service application, where 500 representatives are using the app, if there is one simple rest API which will take a policy-number and does a lookup in HDFS or Cassandra using Apache Spark. Does is make sense to use

1. One Spark-Context per request
2. One Singleton-Spark context for all requests
3. Create a pool of Spark-Contexts and use it

Thanks for your response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark context contains access information of your cluster,appname and running cores plus some application level properties.
So One singleton Spark context would be the ultimate one in Large scale applications.

Check out [Spark Job server](https://spark-summit.org/2014/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Spark-Job-Server-Easy-Spark-Job-Management-Chan-Chu.pdf) for more details

Comment: So the point is Spark-context or otherwise Spark jobs are for processing very big-data in a batch-mode. process 10GB file for some information etc ...

Comment: So the point is Spark-context or otherwise Spark jobs are for processing very big-data in a batch-mode. process 10GB file for some information etc ...   In the example I have quoted above if there are 500 requests waiting for a job ... setting up a park-jobserver would be helpful ... what is the adoption of this service ... is any big-enterprise using it ... thanks Yash

Comment: Yes @Manjesh when you see the github link of spark job server by ooyala , you can see that its being used by more than 17 companies.